# Why was I not awarded the bounty by the community?

Tags: support

[ORM on which standards i can select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544704/orm-on-which-standards-i-can-select/4545298#4545298)

I had the most votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The person who had started the bounty didn't award the bounty before it has expired. This means that it was auto awarded. You didn't receive the bounty amount because you answered the question before the bounty had started so you weren't eligible for the auto-award.

[Bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> **What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?**
>
> **What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered?**
>
> **What is automatic awarding?**
>
> At the end of the bounty period, if
>   the bounty starter has not manually
>   awarded the bounty, eligible answers
>   can be automatically awarded half the
>   bounty amount. The criteria for an
>   answer to be eligible for automatic
>   awarding are as follows:
>
> - The answer must be given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
>
> If two or more eligible answers have
>   the same score, the oldest answer is
>   awarded the bounty.
>
> If no answers meet these criteria, the
>   bounty ends without it being awarded
>   to any answer, and is not refunded to
>   the bounty starter.
>
> An accepted answer that does not meet
>   the above criteria is still ignored by
>   the automatic-awarding system.

Comment: I do not agree with the rule that says that the answer must be created AFTER the bounty. Since the OP obviously didn't mark and answer, the community should decide, even if the answer was created before.

Comment: The bounty was added after your answer so it obviously didn't fulfil the OP requirements. Your answer is therefore disregarded in relation to auto awarding the bounty. Them's the rules I'm afraid.  The community has decided that your answer was the best as your answer currently has the most upvotes.